# Eclipse plugin stopped working after update

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, updates

I updated the Eclipse plugins (Help - Check for update). Since the restart after installation, the plugins aren't working any longer. They're still enlisted in "installation details", but there are no Android preferences, no Android menu entries, no editor ("Could not open the editor: No editor descriptor for id com.android.ide.eclipse.editors.manifest.ManifestEditor"), and so on. I tried to un- and reinstall the plugins with no success. I'm using Eclipse Helileo with Ubuntu. Any idea how I could get my Android IDE working again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you also update the SDK tools? i.e clicking the little Android with the arrow icon and letting it check for updates then installing the updates.

Comment: No i clicked on Help>Check for updates and then installed those updates

Comment: Well update the SDK as well, click the Android Icon in Eclipse, it will check for updates them select the tools stuff at least and update it.

Comment: I cannot even see Android Icon in Eclipse, and even then I have Android SDK updated already.

Answer (score 0):

the problem come from  the compatibility of the plugin versions and the version of the jdk/sdk
if you have the last plugin , you must have the last version of jdk/sdk 
try to  download the last revision of sdk android , with the last jdk java 
and lanch again the eclipse .

good luck my freind

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem several times. Sadly, the only sure-fire solution I've found is to remove ~/.eclipse and reinstall the Android Eclipse plugin (http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html). There is talk that it's fixable just by modifying the bundles.info file (http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=587657) but I never managed to get it working that way.